# Cluj-Napoca Sitecore Meetup: Sitecore Community meetup #7 from Wednesday, December 4, 2019

Tags: discussion, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Wednesday, December 4, 2019 6:00 PM
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Wednesday, December 4, 2019 4:00 PM
- **Location:** Silicon Forest 2, Strada Deva nr. 1-7, Cluj-Napoca, Cluj, Romania
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Cluj-Napoca-Sitecore-Meetup/events/266312303/)
- **Contact:** [Meetup Organizers](https://www.meetup.com/Cluj-Napoca-Sitecore-Meetup/)
- **Agenda:**

  - Using and Customizing SXA - Peter Procházka (online) https://twitter.com/chorpo
  - Sitecore servers provisioning and continues integration using Azure Pipelines - Alina Fodor
  - Roundtables - all of us split into 3 groups.